# Can you use "later on" to replace "next" and "then"?

Tags: word-choice

Example:

> At first, I though it was a star, but then I realized it was an
>   UFO.

Can I use "later" to replace "then" and keep the meaning more or less the same?

> At first, I though it was a star, but later on I realized it was an
>   UFO.

Comment: a minor nit:  Normally **UFO** is pronounced "you-eff-oh", so it takes *a* as the article, not *an*.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the comma after "at first" seems wrong? Look at this similar sentence: At first glance I thought it was a star, later I realized it was a (not an) UFO.

Comment: I would opt for _later_ without the _on_: _At first I thought it was a UFO, but later I realized it was only a star._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Then* is immediate, *later on* means a point in the future.

using your example,

> At first, I though it was a star, but then I realized it was an UFO.

implies that the thought of what the object is changed while you were looking at the object, but

> At first, I though it was a star, but later on I realized it was an UFO.

implies that the initial thought was that the object was a star, but later in time, you changed your mind, having thought through what was seen.

Comment: Thanks, so in brief, "then" can only be replaced by "next?"

Comment: ‘Next’ means something different again, and it would sound fairly awkward in this sentence.

Comment: *next* would be part of a sequence of events, and no particular timeframe can be inferred

Comment: @janoChen: Hard to tell for sure - you haven't really communicated what you are trying to say.